# Error parsing integer in IE11 Enterprise Mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I am extracting the day, month, and year from a date string by calling `split` to get each section of the string, and then parsing them individually with `parseInt`. This is working in Chrome and Edge, but it is not working correctly in IE11 Enterprise Mode.

This is how the data is populating. But the issue is in `03`. It should return as `3`. If I run the same code in Chrome and Edge, it returns `3` rather than `03`.

Can someone help me resolve this?

```
var inputDateText = $(this).val(); //30/03/2021
var splitComponents = inputDateText.split('/');  //[30,03,2021]

if (splitComponents.length > 0) {
    var day = parseInt(splitComponents[0]); //30
    var month = parseInt(splitComponents[1]); //03
    var year = parseInt(splitComponents[2]); //2021
```

Comment: `parseInt` returns the number value of the string given. A number does not have a leading zero. Also, it requires a radix if not in strict mode, especially with strings starting with zeros.

Comment: Hi @HereticMonkey, the same works fine in Chrome and Edge but not in Enterprise mode. I will get return `3` in Chrome but `03` in enterprise mode.Can you please provide solution for this.

Comment: I know this answer will be very basic, but can you try 
if (splitComponets[1].charAt(0) == "0")
{
splitComponets[1] = splitComponets[1].replace("0","");
}

Comment: Use a radix, as the duplicate mentions. However, I tried this code in Enterprise mode in IE11, and was unable to reproduce the situation. I get `3` for `month`.